# scroll only next card view in Recyclerview even howmuch scroll amount applied

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

Scroll in Recyclerview list of card view default when scroll faster than scroll more than one card.I need only shows next of current card when scrolling even user how much scroll amount is applied in android.I Googled but not getting a solution. thanks for helping
my code contained MyRecyclerView and LinearLayoutManager looks following lines

```
MyRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
MyRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager MyLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    MyLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    if (listitems.size() > 0 & MyRecyclerView != null) {
        MyRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(listitems));
    }
    MyRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(MyLayoutManager);
```

Comment: actually what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using object of linearLayoutManager.Use this line to move the selected item to show on top of recycler screen.

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(YOUR_ITEM_POSITION,OFFSET_YOU_WANT);
```

For more information on how to use scrollToPositionWithOffset check this link .

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#scrollToPositionWithOffset(int,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You should use  **[smoothScrollToPosition(int position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)**

> Starts a smooth scroll to an adapter position.

```
recyclerview.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

**2.** Use **[scrollToPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)**

> `void scrollToPosition (int position)`
>
> Convenience method to scroll to a certain position. RecyclerView does not implement scrolling logic, rather forwards the call to

```
RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(postion)
```

**3.** `rv.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(youPositionInTheAdapter).`

**4.** **[scrollToPositionWithOffset()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#scrollToPositionWithOffset(int,%20int))**

> `void scrollToPositionWithOffset (int position,int offset)`
>
> Scroll to the specified adapter position with the given offset from resolved layout start. Resolved layout start depends on `getReverseLayout()`, `getLayoutDirection(android.view.View)` and `getStackFromEnd().`

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(1, 10);
```